# How to include a WebGL project in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've got a small Unity game, and I'm trying to export it using WebGL so it can be included in our Rails app... that said, I have no idea where to place the files or what to do with them so that they will be picked up properly. Through stabbing in the dark, I've been able to get the data/code/memUrl values to point at the files (or at least stop erroring at me), but I had to add 'gz' to the file extensions to get them picked up, so I don't know if that broke anything.

I'v put UnityLoader.js in public/javascripts,Release folder in public.
I'm getting some JS errors like this:

```
Invoking error handler due to
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
blob:http://localhost:3000/d38265a6-af46-425c-acd0-6eba9d0d5cd9:1
```

Here my html.erb

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var Module = {
      TOTAL_MEMORY: 268435456,
      errorhandler: null,           // arguments: err, url, line. This function must return 'true' if the error is handled, otherwise 'false'
      compatibilitycheck: null,
      dataUrl: "Release/TestExternCall.datagz",
      codeUrl: "TestExternCall.jsgz",
      memUrl: "Release/TestExternCall.memgz",
    };
    </script>

<%= javascript_include_tag 'UnityLoader'%>
```

Does anyone have a line on a tutorial that walks through how to include WebGL output in a Rails app? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you put the error in code block instead of an image ?

Comment: @XavM Sorry, I've put the error in code block. Please help..